# Update value equal to the count of not appearance on the last X records

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table where a number between 0 and 99 is inserted every now an then. Every time a new value is inserted I need to count how many numbers between 0 and 99 does not appears in the last 100 previous records and update `not_in_last_100_repetitions`.

You can assume the structure of my table is:

```
num (int, primary, auto-increment) | winner (varchar) | not_in_last_100_repetitions (int)
```

You can know the previous 100 numbers qith a select and ordering by `num`.

I prepared this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a0a2e

Comment: Why do you have to update anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to update the column via trigger? or as a separate statement?

Anyway, the following calculates how many from the range `0-99` are not present in the 100 last records:

```
select 100 - count(distinct winner) 
from mytable 
where num >= (select max(num) from mytable) - 100
```

Comment: Hm, my head hurts.